# How can i fetch 'img' src attribute by scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I wanna to use scrapy to fetch the img's links so i write the program below in scrapy's crawler:

```
hxs.select('//dl[@class="clearfix"]//img/@src/text()').extract()
```

However, it's doesn't work anyway. is there any problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`text()` is the text of the element. Just use `@src`:

```
hxs.select('//dl[@class="clearfix"]//img/@src').extract()
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using CSS selectors instead of XPath, the syntax is `::attr(src)`

```py
response.css('.product-list img::attr(src)').extract() # extract_first() to get only one
```